# Clear interrupts and reading writing ports

Tags: assembly, kernel, hard-drive

In assembler at the kernel level, if we issue a `cli` to disable interrupts, can we then subsequently issue a port read/write for hard disk read write? In other words, can a hard disk driver be implemented with synchronous read/write? Something like:

```
cli
// Do file system stuff
// at block level
// read/write a block using in/out assembler instructions
sti
```

Comment: See [here](http://wiki.osdev.org/ATA_PIO_Mode#Polling_the_Status_vs._IRQs) for information about ATA PIO mode (the simplest mode). That page has all of the info you need to write a PIO driver. Basically, you need to select the drive, disable IRQs for the drive (so that you don't actually have to disable interrupts), send your command, poll the status port, and read the data a word at a time.